# How to use errno from asm?

Tags: linux, assembly

I'm trying to create a small executable on a 64 bit Linux system.  All I need to do is read from stdin and write to stdout so I thought that a good way to shrink it could be to avoid using libc and staticly link my own functions which would directly call the read(2) and write(2) syscalls instead.  (It turns out I also needed exit(2) as well.)  So after some experimentation I came up with the following assembler code which I link with the rest of the program written in C.

It mostly works except for one thing.  The libc functions that wrap read and write set errno in case of an error.  I can't get this to work.  No big deal for this particular project but it will be important if I decide to write a mini-stdio on top of these functions.  So here is the code.  Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
.global sys_exit
.global sys_read
.global sys_write
.global errno

.text
sys_exit:
    movq $60, %rax  # exit syscall = 60
    syscall
    ret

sys_read:
    movq $0, %rax   # read syscall = 0
    syscall
    jc error
    ret

sys_write:
    movq $1, %rax   # write syscall = 1
    syscall
    jc error
    ret

error:
    movl $60, errno
    ret

.bss
errno: .INT 0
```

This is a sample c program which uses those functions:

```
#define stdin 0
#define stdout 1
extern int errno;

void _start() {
    char c;

    if (sys_read(stdin, &c, 1) < 0) {
        sys_exit(errno);
    }

    if (sys_write(stdout, &c, 1) < 0) {
        sys_exit(errno);
    }

    sys_exit(0);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so after some more reading I think I have it now:

```
.global sys_exit
.global sys_read
.global sys_write
.global errno

.text
sys_exit:
    movq $60, %rax  # exit syscall = 60
    syscall
    ret

sys_read:
    movq $0, %rax   # read syscall = 0
    syscall
    cmpl $0, %eax
    jl error
    ret

sys_write:
    movq $1, %rax   # write syscall = 1
    syscall
    cmpl $0, %eax
    jl error
    ret

error:
    neg  %eax
    movl %eax, errno
    movl $-1, %eax
    ret

.bss
errno: .INT 0
```

Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: `errno` is set by `libc`. The raw system calls return the error in `EAX` as a negative number.

Comment: I know libc sets errno.  I am trying to mimic that functionality.  I did not feel that the questions suggested as duplicates really answer that but I will look over them again and try and figure it out.

Comment: As far as I know syscalls don't set flags so checking for the carry flag being set is probably not going to get you anything. You probably want to be checking for the return value in _RAX_ and doing something with `errno` if _RAX_ signals an error.

Comment: It's explained there: **Note that the last paragraph describes how the glibc wrapper decodes the value and sets errno to -EAX if the raw system call's return value is negative, so errno=EFAULT and return -1 if the raw system call returned -EFAULT.**

Comment: @Jaldhar I told you *how* libc sets `errno` from the value returned by the system call. You can do the same thing. If `EAX` is negative, it's the negative value of `errno`.

Comment: useless micro optimization (with bug fix?): you can change the test to `test %rax,%rax` `js error` ... BTW, you are comparing `eax`, while in 64b linux the syscall return value is 64b in `rax` (according to teh internets, I didn't verify with real code). Also I'm not sure about the `error:` handler itself, the `neg` and store of errno is probably fine (errno 1..4095 IIRC), but then the -1 .. I would rather load whole `rax` with that one (as you have CF=1 from `neg`, you can do `sbb %rax,%rax` to set `rax = -1`).

Comment: @Ped7g  Thanks for the tips.  The reason I used %eax is because errno is an int which is 32 bits.  I thought it might be marginally "better" to use a 32 bit register.  However it seems it doesn't really make a difference to size or speed plus your way ensures I don't accidentally leave junk in the upper 32 bits of %rax.

Comment: @Jaldhar I don't think so, according to [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/syscalls.h#L563) the `sys_read` returns `long`, not `int` (and `int` is not guaranteed to be 32 bit either BTW), so I would expect the `sys_read` to return full 64b `rax`, if you would read from file 2-3GiB of data, your test would catch the returned 2+G value as error. ... I mean, the `errno` itself may be 32b, but the return value of `syscall` looks to be 64b. (as errno may be up to -4095 IIRC, so it does of course fit into 32b well)